# Make a new df keeping 1 duplicate datetime but conserve row values of the other duplicates on pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 DF like this

```
Date                  A      B      C
2021-01-01 22:00:00   true   false  false
2021-01-01 22:00:00   false  true   false
2021-01-01 22:00:00   false  false  true
```

And I need to make a new df without duplicate values but conserving the rows values of the duplicates, like this:

```
Date                  A      B      C
2021-01-01 22:00:00   true   true   true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby:

```
df.groupby('Date').max()
```

Comment: Yeah but this gave me only the date but not keep the values from the other duplicates
I need to take the true values of all rows and put in only one.

I need to create a new df with the date and take the true value of A, true value of B, true value of C, and put all in one row without the false values